# How can I produce a fixed length of numbers that sum up a given number in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm new to haskell world and wanted to know, given any positive integer and number of digits between 1-9 how can I find the **combination** of  numbers that sum into the positive integer using the provided number of digits in *Haskell*. For example,
4 using two digits can be represented as a list of  `[[2,2],[3,1]]` using three digits as a list of  `[[1,1,2]]`,
5 using two digits can be represented as a list of  `[[2,3],[4,1]]` using three digits as a list of `[[1,1,3],[2,2,1]]`

Comment: FYI, the problem you're trying to solve is called "finding the [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) of an integer".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want to avoid a brute-force approach, this can be regarded as a typical [dynamic-programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) problem:

```
import Data.Array

partitions :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
partitions m n = table ! (m, n, 9)
  where
    table   = listArray ((1, 1, 1), (m, n, 9)) l
    l       = [f i j k | i <- [1 .. m], j <- [1 .. n], k <- [1 .. 9]]

    f i 1 k = if i > k `min` 9 then [] else [[i]]
    f i j k = [d : ds | d <- [1 .. k `min` pred i], ds <- table ! (i - d, j - 1, d)]
```

The idea is to construct a three-dimensional lazy array `table` in which a cell with index `(i, j, k)` contains all partitions `ds` of the positive integer `i` into lists of `j` digits drawn from `[1 .. k]` such that `sum ds == i`.

For example:

```
> partitions 4 2
[[2,2],[3,1]]

> partitions 4 3
[[2,1,1]]

> partitions 5 2
[[3,2],[4,1]]

> partitions 5 3
[[2,2,1],[3,1,1]]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really don't want to *think* about the problem, and you really should because dynamic programming is good brain food, then you can ask the computer to be smart on your behalf.  For example, you could use a tool called an SMT solver to which the `sbv` package gives you easy access.

**Encoding Partitioning in SBV**

A great advantage of solvers is you merely need to express the problem and not the solution.  In this case lets declare some number of integers (identified by `len`) which are values `1..9` that sum to a known result (`sumVal`):

```
intPartitions :: Int -> Int -> IO AllSatResult
intPartitions sumVal len = allSat $ do
    xs <- mapM exists [show i | i <- [1..len]] :: Symbolic [SWord32]
    mapM (constrain . (.< 10)) xs
    mapM (constrain . (.> 0)) xs
    return $ sum xs .== fromIntegral sumVal
```

Calling this function is rather simple we just have to import the right libraries and print out what are called the satisfying "models" for our problem:

```
import Data.SBV
import Data.List (nub,sort)

main = do
    res <- intPartitions 5 3 
    print (nub (map sort (extractModels res :: [[Word32]])))
```

Notice I sorted and eliminated duplicate solutions because you didn't seem to care that `[1,1,3]`, `[3,1,1]` etc were all solutions - you just want one permutation of the resulting assignments.

For these hard-coded values we have a result of:

```
[[1,1,3],[1,2,2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well a simple brute force does the trick:

```
import Data.List
import Control.Monad

sums :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
sums number count = nub . map sort . filter ((==number) . sum) $ replicateM count [1..number+1-count]
```

Note that this is **very** inefficient. The usage of `nub . map sort` only shortens the result by removing doubled elements.

Comment: The trick indeed works .. but how can I limit the elements so that it's going to be represented between the numbers 1 upto 9. Infact the number of elements that represent the sum must be at most 9.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually solved by using dynamic programming to avoid recomputing common sub-problems. But this is not the most important problem here: you need to start by coming up with the recursive algorithm! You will have plenty of time to think about producing an efficient solution once you've solved that problem. Hence this answer in two steps. The whole gist without comments [is available here](https://gist.github.com/gallais/72d425888da92b44a57e).

I start off by giving names to types because I'd get confused with all the `Int`s floating around and I consider types to be documentation. You might be more clever than I am and not need all this extra stuff.

```
type Target = Int
type Digits = Int
type MaxInt = Int
```

Now, the bruteforce solution: We're given the number of `Digits` left to partition a number, the `Target` number and the `MaxInt` we may use in this partition.

```
partitionMaxBrute :: Digits -> Target -> MaxInt -> [[Int]]
partitionMaxBrute d t m
```

If we have no digits left and the target is zero, we're happy!

```
  | d == 0 && t == 0               = [[]]
```

If the product of `Digits` by `MaxInt` is smaller than `Target` or if the `MaxInt` itself is smaller than zero, there is no way we may succeed accumulating `Digits` non-zero numbers! :(

```
  | d * m < t || m <= 0            = []
```

If `MaxInt` is bigger than our `Target` then we better decrease `MaxInt` if we want to have a solution. It does not make sense to decrease it to anything bigger than `Target` + 1 - `Digits`.

```
  | t < m                          = partitionMaxBrute d t (t + 1 - d)
```

Finally, we may either lower `MaxInt` (we are not using that number) or substract `MaxInt` from `Target` and keep going (we are using `MaxInt` at least once):

```
  | otherwise                      = partitionMaxBrute d t (m - 1)
                                  ++ fmap (m :) (partitionMaxBrute (d - 1) (t - m) m)
```

Given that solution, we can get our brute force partition: it's the one where the `MaxInt` we start with is `Target + 1 - Digits` which makes sense given that we are expecting a list of `Digits` non-zero numbers.

```
partitionBrute :: Digits -> Target -> [[Int]]
partitionBrute d t = partitionMaxBrute d t (t + 1 - d)
```

Now comes the time of memoization: dynamic programming is taking advantage of the fact that the smaller problems we solve are discovered through a lot of different paths and we do not need to recompute the answer over and over again. Easy caching is made possible by the [memoize](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/memoize) package. We simply write the **same** function with its recursive calls abstracted:

```
partitionMax :: (Digits -> Target -> MaxInt -> [[Int]]) ->
                 Digits -> Target -> MaxInt -> [[Int]]
partitionMax rec d t m
  | d == 0 && t == 0               = [[]]
  | d * m < t || m <= 0            = []
  | t < m                          = rec d t (t + 1 - d)
  | otherwise                      = rec d t (m - 1)
                                  ++ fmap (m :) (rec (d - 1) (t - m) m)
```

And make sure that we cache the values:

```
partition :: Digits -> Target -> [[Int]]
partition d t = memoPM d t (t + 1 - d)
  where memoPM = memoize3 $ partitionMax memoPM
```

Answer (score 0):

You can produce all partitions directly:

```
type Count  = Int
type Max    = Int
type Target = Int

partitions :: Count -> Max -> Target -> [[Int]]
partitions 0 m 0 = [[]]
partitions k m n = do
    let m' = min m (n - k + 1)
    d <- takeWhile (\d -> n <= k * d) [m', m' - 1 .. 1]
    map (d:) $ partitions (k - 1) d (n - d)
```

It's easy to check, that there are no redundant cases. We just need to replace `do` with `redundant $ do`, where `redundant` is

```
redundant [] = [[]]
redundant xs =  xs
```

If `partitions (k - 1) d (n - d)` returned `[]`, then `redundant` would make `[[]]` from it, and then `map (d:) $ partitions (k - 1) d (n - d)` would be equal to `[d]`. But output doesn't change with the `redundant` function, so all partitions are generated directly.

The code is pretty simple and fast, since you want to produce partitions, rather than count them.